# Debugging Seemingly Random Exceptions in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, exception

I have been at this for days and asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18007205/app-crashes-when-navigating-away-from-loading-collection-view) a few days ago. I thought it's probably better to rephrase the question more clearly.

I have a series of UICollectionViewControllers inside a UINavigationController. Each time the user makes a selection, a new collection view is pushed on the screen and this collection view is responsible for fetching its content from an API.

*Sometimes* there's a crash at this point. The exceptions are different each time. Usually, it's one of the following:

```
*** Collection <NSConcreteMapTable: 0x1922cf60> was mutated while being enumerated.
```

OR

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: '*** Collection <__NSSetM: 0x203f26b0> was mutated while being enumerated.'
```

Sometimes it doesn't even throw an exception but the program will pause in an "empty thread" saying `error: address doesn't contain a section that points to a section in a object file`. Finally, this error is more consistently reproducible when an item is selected, the new view is pushed, and then the back button is quickly pressed as soon as it appears. But it can also happen without the back button being pushed.

I have attached my own uncaught exception handler to print out the stack trace. In all cases, none of my own classes are in the trace.

I have 'break on exception' set but it never stops anywhere meaningful - usually some nondescript assembly code that just reads `trap` or in UIApplicationMain.

So my question is: **Where do I even begin debugging this?**

I can post an example of a stack trace if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

First, set an exception breakpoint in Xcode. It will stop *before* the exception is thrown, so you know who caused it.

What seems to be happening is that you have code

```
for (id object in somearray) ...
```

and while that loop is running, someone modifies somearray. That is fatal. You probably have to think about how you are writing your code. For example, you can just write

for (id object in [somearray copy]) ...

and then you can modify somearray as much as you like. Maybe your code just isn't thread safe and another thread modifies somearray while one thread is iterating through it.